# Looping through NSMutableArray in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can Ioop through an NSMutableArray in Swift? What I have tried:

```
var vehicles = NSMutableArray()
```

The array contains objects from class: `Vehicle`

```
for vehicle in vehicles {
    println(vehicle.registration)
}
```

I cannot run the above code without the compiler telling me `registration` doesn't belong to `AnyObject`. At this point I assumed that was because I hadn't told the for loop what type of class `item` belongs to. So I modified by code:

```
for vehicle: Vehicle in vehicles {
    println(vehicle.registration)
}
```

Now the compiler complains about downcasting... how can I simply gain access to the custom registration property whilst looping through the array of Vehicles?

Comment: Does this help? http://dev.eltima.com/post/96538497489/convert-nsmutablearray-to-swift-array

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This should work:

```
for vehicle in (vehicles as NSArray as! [Vehicle]) {
    println(vehicle.registration) 
}
```

Comment: And how to do it for NSMutableArray?

Comment: Rob's answer is better: why force an optional when you don't have to?

Answer (score 17):

As Romain suggested, you can use Swift array. If you continue to use `NSMutableArray`, you could do either:

```
for object in vehicles {
    if let vehicle = object as? Vehicle {
        print(vehicle.registration)
    }
}
```

or, you can force unwrap it, using a `where` qualifier to protect yourself against cast failures:

```
for vehicle in vehicles where vehicle is Vehicle {
    print((vehicle as! Vehicle).registration)
}
```

or, you can use functional patterns:

```
vehicles.compactMap { $0 as? Vehicle }
    .forEach { vehicle in
        print(vehicle.registration)
}
```

---

Obviously, if possible, the question is whether you can retire `NSMutableArray` and use `Array<Vehicle>` (aka `[Vehicle]`) instead. So, instead of:

```
let vehicles = NSMutableArray()
```

You can do:

```
var vehicles: [Vehicle] = []
```

Then, you can do things like:

```
for vehicle in vehicles {
    print(vehicle.registration)
}
```

Sometimes we're stuck with Objective-C code that's returning `NSMutableArray` objects, but if this `NSMutableArray` was created in Swift, it's probably preferable to use `Array<Vehicle>` instead.

Answer (score 4):

`NSMutableArray` comes from the Objective-C world. Now you can use generics and strongly-typed arrays, like this:

```
var vehicles = [Vehicle]()
...
for vehicle in vehicles {
    println(vehicle.registration)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would I be able to use the `removeObjectsAtIndexes` method on your `vehicles` array? I am converting an NSArray to an array that allows me to use that for technical reasons in my app... as long that works your answer is perfect

Comment: Sure. Swift arrays don't provide this method natively, but you can code your own without much trouble: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173565/removeobjectsatindexes-for-swift-arrays (see the answer that has most upvotes, it is not the accepted one but most valid one)