# Swift remove objects in Array range

Tags: arrays, swift, range

I have an array as a property in a class.

```
Class Custom {
 let objArray: [CustomClass]
}
```

I want to remove some items in objArray in a range. So I have done below

```
let newVar  = objArray[1...3]
```

new objects are correctly removed but return value is in  newVar since array is value type  how I can make the original reflect the same.

Below code gets Index out of bounds as the indexes incremented

```
for i in 1...3 {

  objArray.remove(at: 1)
}
```

======

What is the best approach for the above issue.

Any hint in right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are removing from `1st` index every time. And you can not remove object from array in loop after first time removing array count will be change so it will probably crash.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `removeSubrange` method of array. Make a valid `range` by element `location` and `length`.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
let range = 1...3
array.removeSubrange(range)

print(array)
```

**Output:** `[1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

***Note:*** Range should be a valid range I mean it should not be out from array.

**Here is yours way (by for loop)**
We can not remove objects by their indexes in a loop because every time object removes array's count and objects indexes will be change so out of range crash can come or you might get a wrong output. So you will have to take help of another array. See below example:-

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
var newArray: [Int] = []
let minRange = 1
let maxRange = 3
for i in 0..<array.count {
     if i >= minRange && i <= maxRange {
        /// Avoid
        continue
     }

     newArray.append(array[i])
}

print(newArray)
```

**Output:** `[1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

Comment: Getting this warning --- Legacy Constructor Violation: Swift constructors are preferred over legacy convenience functions. (legacy_constructor

Comment: instead of NSMakeRange can we use something swift

Comment: Which swift version you are using? Its in `Swift 4.0`

Comment: We have some validators for Swift that's giving the warning to not use NSMakeRange instead use something swift. In normal Xcode u may not receive the same

Comment: @Ekra Its pretty easy like you use in for loop. See my edited answer. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove items by index in a range **you have to inverse the indexes** to start with the highest index otherwise you will get the out-of-range exception. Consider also that indexes are zero-based.

That's a safe version which checks also the upper bound of the array.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in (0...3).reversed() where i < array.count {
    array.remove(at: i)
}

print(array) // [5, 6]
```

You can find a more generic and more efficient solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173565/removeobjectsatindexes-for-swift-arrays/50835467#50835467)

Comment: Very nice, clean and good working solution, I actually prefer yours for it's simplicity and good use of swift syntax.

Answer (score 2):

#### This solution also returns the removed values

```
extension Array {
   /**
    * ## Examples:
    * var arr = [0,1,2,3]
    * arr.remove((0..<2)) // 0,1
    * arr // 2,3
    */
   mutating func remove(_ range: Range<Int>) -> Array {
      let values = Array(self[range])
      self.removeSubrange(range)
      return values
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that an array index is zero based, which is to say, the first element in an array is accessed bv:

```
Let firstArrayValue = objArray[0]
```

So in the case of your for loop, you need to subtact 1 from i to get the proper index value:

for i in 1…3 {

objArray.remove(at: i-1)
}

A better way is to loop through the indices by starting at 0.  i = 0 will reference the first value in your objArray:

```
for i in 0...2 {
    objArray.remove(at: i)
}
```

If you need to remove elements in the middle of the array you must first find their index location then remove.  To find the index:

```
let indexLocation = objArray(indexOf: "Value in Array")
```

Then remove:

```
objArray.remove(at: indexLocation)
```

Comment: `objArray.remove(at: i)` will give wrong output. Because after removing first time array count and elements indexes will be change.

Comment: i need to remove the objects from middle of array

Comment: I'll update my answer.  You have to first locate the index of the elements you want to remove.  Then remove them.  It's a two step process.