# How convert [Int] to int?

Tags: swift, swift4

I have code like this

```
let index = tableView.selectedRowIndexes.map { Int($0) }
        arrDomains.remove(at: index)
```

But got error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[Int]' to expected argument type 'Int'

How convert [Int] to int?

*Swift 4, macOS*

Comment: That depends on the result you're expecting. You have an array of the selected _rows_. Do you only care about the first selected row or perhaps the last selected row? Alternatively, maybe it would be better to enumerate all the selected rows and remove all of them.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Thanks for attention. You are right it would be better to get all the selected lines and delete them. But I do not really understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`index` is array of Int. But you need to pass `Int` to the `remove` method.

If you want to remove all objects for selected row indexes, than write:

```
let indexes = tableView.selectedRowIndexes.map { Int($0) }
indexes.reversed().forEach { arrDomains.remove(at: $0) }
```

If you want to remove object at some index, than write:

```
guard let index = tableView.selectedRowIndexes.map { Int($0) }.first(where: { /*.your condition here */ }) else { return }
arrDomains.remove(at: $0)
```

Answer (score 5):

*Index**es*** is plural that means there are multiple values

`selectedRowIndexes` returns an `IndexSet` object. You could use `forEach` but you have to reverse the indexes otherwise you get the famous *mutating-while-iterating-out-of-range* error.

```
let indexes = tableView.selectedRowIndexes
indexes.reversed().forEach{ arrDomains.remove(at: $0) }
```

Mapping the `indexSet` to `[Int]` is redundant.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173565/removeobjectsatindexes-for-swift-arrays/50835467#50835467) is an optimized `remove(at indexes: IndexSet)` method.