# Filter huge array optimising performance

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, search

I have an array with over 300k objects which I'm showing in a `UITableView`. When filtering by prefix match using the `filter` method, the first search takes a bit over 60s! After that, the search is way faster taking around 1s, which I'd still want to improve a bit more.

The object looks like this:

```
struct Book {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let author: String
    let summary: String
}
```

This is how I'm filtering at the moment:

```
filteredBooks = books.filter { $0.title.lowercased().hasPrefix(prefix.lowercased()) }
```

The data comes from a JSON file which I decode using `Codable` (which takes a bit longer than I would like as well). I'm trying to achieve this without a database or any kind of framework implementation nor lazy loading the elements. I'd like to be able to show the 300k objects in the `UITableView` and realtime `filter` with a decent performance.

I've Googled a bit and found the `Binary Search` and `Trie` search algorithms but didn't know how to implement them to be able to use them with `Codable` and my `struct`. Also, maybe replacing the `struct` with another data type would help but not sure which either.

Comment: 300k objects is about the time you should probably start using a database, and not a massive json file.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I know and you are right! But I already know how to use databases. This is a test project to learn how to optimise extreme cases like this by probably using some kind of search algorithms :)

Comment: `Book` has a stride of 56 bytes, so 300K objects should take about 16.8 MB. That's okay, but if you're making lots of copies of big subsets, that would be an issue. Using a trie would work, but you would need your objects to be references types (objects of a class, not a struct). In your case, you could build a prefix tree, for fast prefix queries. However, that would be a shitty user experience, because it would be totally inflexible to typos, common misspellings, etc. You couldn't search the middle of a movie (e.g. you couldn't search `The Fellowship of the Ring`, without the beginning part)

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica thanks for your comment. I already took a look at the `Trie` structure but I could not manage to make a proper implementation using my data structure. About the user experience, that does not worry me too much, at the moment I want to focus on `prefix` match :)

Comment: Isn’t this the same discussion about half stable partitioning that we already had here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173565/removeobjectsatindexes-for-swift-arrays Try `removeAll(where:)` or write your own partitioning algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

Because I liked the challenge I put something together.

It is basically a tree with each layer of the tree containing a title prefix plus the elements with that exact match plus a list of lower trees with each having the same prefix plus one more letter of the alphabet:

```
extension String {
    subscript (i: Int) -> String {
        let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)
        return String(self[start...start])
    }
}

struct Book {
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let author: String
    let summary: String
}

class PrefixSearchable <Element> {
    let prefix: String
    var elements = [Element]()
    var subNodes = [String:PrefixSearchable]()
    let searchExtractor : (Element) -> String

    private init(prefix: String, searchExtractor:@escaping(Element) -> String) {
        self.prefix = prefix
        self.searchExtractor = searchExtractor
    }

    convenience init(_ searchExtractor:@escaping(Element) -> String) {
        self.init(prefix: "", searchExtractor: searchExtractor)
    }

    func add(_ element : Element) {
        self.add(element, search: searchExtractor(element))
    }

    private func add(_ element : Element, search : String) {
        if search == prefix {
            elements.append(element)
        } else {
            let next = search[prefix.count]
            if let sub = subNodes[next] {
                sub.add(element, search: search)
            } else {
                subNodes[next] = PrefixSearchable(prefix: prefix + next, searchExtractor: searchExtractor)
                subNodes[next]!.add(element, search: search)
            }
        }
    }

    func elementsWithChildren() -> [Element] {
        var ele = [Element]()
        for (_, sub) in subNodes {
            ele.append(contentsOf: sub.elementsWithChildren())
        }
        return ele + elements
    }

    func search(search : String) -> [Element] {
        print(prefix)
        if search.count == prefix.count {
            return elementsWithChildren()
        } else {
            let next = search[prefix.count]
            if let sub = subNodes[next] {
                return sub.search(search: search)
            } else {
                return []
            }
        }
    }
}

let searchable : PrefixSearchable<Book> = PrefixSearchable({ $0.title.lowercased() })
searchable.add(Book(id: 1, title: "title", author: "", summary: ""))
searchable.add(Book(id: 2, title: "tille", author: "", summary: ""))

print(searchable.search(search: "ti")) // both books
print(searchable.search(search: "title")) // just one book
print(searchable.search(search: "xxx")) // no books
```

It can probably be improved in terms of readability (my swift is quite rusty right now). I would not guarantee that it works in all corner cases.
You would probably have to add a "search limit" which stops recursively returning all children if no exact match is found.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Given the code structure, I'm not really sure how to use `Codable` to feed `searchable` with the needed data plus add this `PrefixSearchable` as the data source of the `UITableView`... am I missing something very basic maybe?

Comment: @anonymous You don't, you just read all the data as you do now and then call add for each and every parsed object. You *can* change your json file to support the tree itself so that populating the tree is easier, but that is just basic sugar on top of this data structure.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem ended up being `booksTableView.reloadSections([0], with: .automatic)` acting in a very weird way. I guess trying to animate all the cells on first insanely big search. `reloadData()` works just awesomely fast! I wonder why that behaviour tho as I'm dequeuing the cells...

Answer (score 1):

Before your start changing anything, run Instruments and determine where your bottlenecks are. It's very easy to chase the wrong things.

I'm very suspicious of that 60s number. That's a huge amount of time and suggests that you're actually doing this filtering repeatedly. I'm betting you do it once per visible row or something like that. That would explain why it's so much faster the second time. 300k is a lot, but it really isn't that much. Computers are very fast, and a minute is a very long time.

That said, there are some obvious problems with your existing filter. It recomputes `prefix.lowercased()` 300k times, which is unnecessary. you can pull that out:

```
let lowerPrefix = prefix.lowercased()
filteredBooks = books.filter { $0.title.lowercased().hasPrefix(lowerPrefix) }
```

Similarly, you're recomputing all of `title.lowercased()` for every search, and you almost never need all of it. You might cache the lowercased versions, but you also might just lowercase what you need:

```
let lowerPrefix = prefix.lowercased()
let prefixCount = prefix.count // This probably isn't actually worth caching
filteredBooks = books.filter { $0.title.prefix(prefixCount).lowercased() == lowerPrefix }
```

I doubt you'll get a lot of benefit this way, but it's the kind of thing to explore before exploring novel data structures.

That said, if the only kind of search you need is a prefix search, the Trie is definitely designed precisely for that problem. And yeah, binary searching is also worth considering if you can keep your list in title order, and prefix searching is the only thing you care about.

While it won't help your first search, keep in mind that your second search can often be much faster by caching recent searches. In particular, if you've searched "a" already, then you know that "ap" will be a subset of that, so you should use that fact. Similarly, it is very common for these kinds of searches to repeat themselves when users make typos and backspace. So saving some recent results can be a big win, at the cost of memory.

At these scales, memory allocations and copying can be a problem. Your Book type is on the order of 56 bytes:

```
MemoryLayout.stride(ofValue: Book()) // 56
```

(The size is the same, but stride is a bit more meaningful when you think about putting them in an array; it includes any padding between elements. In this case the padding is 0. But if you added a Bool property, you'd see the difference.)

The contents of strings don't have to be copied (if there's no mutation), so it doesn't really matter how long the strings are. But the metadata does have to be copied, and that adds up.

So a full copy of this array is on the order of 16MB of "must copy" data. The largest subset you would expect would be 10-15% (10% of words start with the most common letter, *s*, in English, but titles might skew this some). That's still on the order of a megabyte of copying per filter.

You can improve this by working exclusively in indices rather than full elements. There unfortunately aren't great tools for that in stdlib, but they're not that hard to write.

```
extension Collection {
    func indices(where predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> [Index] {
        indices.filter { predicate(self[$0]) }
    }
}
```

Instead of copying 56 bytes, this copies 8 bytes per result which could significantly reduce your memory churn.

You could also implement this as an IndexSet; I'm not certain which would be faster to work with.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm running it once per character added in the `UITextField`. I added a log and I can see the delegate being fired once per character typed and thus, the `filter` method being called only once. I'll either way run some extra tests and see if there's something going wrong, but I do think it's more a search algorithm O(n) problem...

Comment: BTW, I built a little test harness to check the performance of this. On an iPhone 6S, I'm seeing <1s (0.78s) to filter a 300k element list based on a one-character prefix. This is on the order that I'd expect, and matches your second-run results. I think your 60s result is coming from something else. https://gist.github.com/rnapier/6693048bbc4cd6770d59a20744ec9710

Comment: I'm working on my 2015 i7 Macbook Pro and running the same test -copy&paste- on simulator gives me the following result: `Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 151.860 (151.861) seconds` :/

Comment: You're looking at the wrong value. That's the total length of time to run the test. `.measure()` runs the test many times. Look for a line like `... measured [Time, seconds] average: 0.672, relative standard deviation: 6.276%, ...`

Comment: Xcode will show the value in a gray label that probably reads (unfortunately by default) "No baseline average for Time." Click that and you'll see the actual time. Or click the gray dot in the gutter and it'll show you a graph.

Comment: You are completely right! I'm so sorry, I completely missed the first part of the log. I've done a test with my data and it's actually correct what you say. Is it possible that what lags is setting the filtered results in the data source of the UITableView?

Comment: Found the issue of the slow first search... apparently, reloading the section with automatic animation was making everything take ages `booksTableView.reloadSections([0], with: .automatic)`. I tried using `reloadData()` and boom, 0.2s search. Thank you for your patience!