# Swift: Excluding a specific index from an array when filtering

Tags: arrays, swift

I'd like to filter an array of numbers and use reduce on them, but I need to exclude a specific `index` and I can't divide. Is it possible to do this with methods that are part of `Foundation` in Swift?

I've tried breaking the array into two using `prefix` & `suffix`, but there are some edge cases where it blows up w/ an out of bounds exception.

```
    while currentIndex < nums.count - 2 {
        for _ in nums {
            let prefix = nums.prefix(currentIndex)
            let suffix = nums.suffix(from: currentIndex + 1)
            if prefix.contains(0) || suffix.contains(0) {
                incrementIndex(andAppend: 0)
            }
            let product = Array(prefix + suffix).reduce(1, *)
            incrementIndex(andAppend: product)
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see the `filter` part, and what is `incrementIndex(andAppend:)`? What's the real goal here?

Comment: `filter` only lets me remove a value, not an index, so I didn't include it in my question. `prefix` & `suffix` get the job done for most cases, but not all cases and I'm seeking to figure out how to exclude a specific index. I don't know how many indices I'll have and there are some edge cases which throw out of bounds exception. It seems like something that's build in somewhere to the standard library, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerated()` to convert a sequence(eg. Arrays) to a sequence of tuples with an integer counter and element paired together

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
var c = 1
let value  = a.enumerated().reduce(1) { (_, arg1) -> Int in
    let (index, element) = arg1
    c = index != 2 ? c*element : c
    return c
}
print(value) // prints 1680 i.e. excluding index 2
```

Comment: Can you explain what `c` is in `var c = 1`?

Comment: a temporary value that will hold the multiplication result

Answer (score 1):

> I'm seeking to figure out how to exclude a specific index

What about this sort of thing?

```
var nums2 = nums
nums2.remove(at:[currentIndex])
let whatever = nums2.reduce // ...
```

Where `remove(at:)` is defined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26308410/341994