# Remove objects at specific indexes from Array in Swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, swift5

I have an array of dictionaries and another array which contains indexes from which need to be removed from the first array. I tried making them IndexSet and using the removeObjects(at: indexes:IndexSet) but fails. Anyone has any idea how to do this?

```
print(listArray.count)
print(listToBeRemoved.count)`
let set = NSMutableIndexSet()
for (idx, index) in listToBeRemoved.enumerated(){
     set.add((index as! NSIndexPath).row)
     if idx == listToBeRemoved.count-1{
     listArray.removeObjects(at: set as IndexSet)
}
print(listArray.count)
```

log prints:
111
24
87
but the problem is that the listArray contains the same object in of all its indexes. Before removing the objects all objects are different as intended.

ListArray is an array of dictionaries where dictionary has 4 keys:

```
{
    Date = Date();
    Source = String;
    Title = String;
    Url = String;
}
```

whereas listToBeRemoved is an array of IndexPaths e.g.:

```
(
"<NSIndexPath: 0xf7e2dd0ccbb6f985> {length = 2, path = 0 - 63}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0xf7e2dd0cc916f985> {length = 2, path = 0 - 42}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0xf7e2dd0cc936f985> {length = 2, path = 0 - 43}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0xf7e2dd0cc9b6f985> {length = 2, path = 0 - 47}",
"<NSIndexPath: 0xf7e2dd0cca56f985> {length = 2, path = 0 - 48}"
```

)

Any advice? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show what `listArray` and `listToBeRemoved` are? It would make debugging easier

Comment: `let indices = listToBeRemoved.map{ $0.row }.sorted();  indices.reversed().forEach{ listArray.remove(at: $0) }` ?

Comment: @aheze edited my question. thanks

Comment: @Larme Already tried that before... seems to break my dictionaries and still produces multiple same objects

Comment: It shouldn't break anything. But does `listToBeRemoved` contains duplicates values. If so, that needs to be fixed with `let indices = Array(Set(listToBeRemoved.map{ $0.row })).sorted()`.

Comment: @Larme no, its does not contain duplicates. This is the log after your suggestion (let indices = listToBeRemoved.map{ ($0 as AnyObject).row }.sorted()ndices.reversed().forEach{ listArray.remove($0) }
print(listArray.count)        112
24
112. So it does not remove the objects..

Comment: remove(at:), not remove().

Comment: And why do you use what I guess be NSArray and NSDictionary ? Use Swift equivalent native

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224751/discussion-between-snksnk-and-larme).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26173565/removeobjectsatindexes-for-swift-arrays/50835467#50835467

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do:

- Get all indices
- Sort them descending
- Iterate over the indices, and remove the item at that index

Why reversed? Because else, imagine you have the indices [0, 1], and your array is [A, B, C]
If you start looping on the indices, you'll have :
0: Remove first from [A, B, C] -> [B, C]
1: Remove second from [B, C] -> [B]

So, if you are using Swift Array:

```
let indices = listToBeRemoved.map{ $0.row }.sorted()
indices.reversed().forEach{ listArray.remove(at: $0) }
```

Since you are using NSMutableArray (I'd strongly recommend you to avoir NSStuff when Stuff is available): `listArray.remove(at: $0)` is `listArray.removeObject(at: $0)`

Another possible solution:

```
let indices = IndexSet(listToBeRemoved.map{ $0.row })
listArray.removeObjects(at: indices) //Objective-C
listArray.remove(atOffsets: indices) //Swift
```